# Ubuntu Install 13.10 - media change

Tags: installation, raid

I'm in the middle of an install of 13.10 on a Poweredge with RAID 5 setup. It is asking for a "media change" and "release AMD64 Salamander (20131016)".

I have the CD in the CD drive, but it won't go forward with the install even though I have the correct disc.

Thinking that maybe the disc as damaged I downloaded the ISO again and burned it, with no errors.

Why is the install asking for this?

Comment: What action were you doing for this message to appear? What's the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`? Edit your question and add the asked information. Please don't use comments (these are comments).

Comment: We are in the middle of installing a new/clean version of Ubuntu. I nuked the entire drive, booted off the cd and then let it run. Came back about 30 minutes later and the install stopped asking for the files.

Comment: And I'm not sure if this matters, but I let Ubuntu handle the RAID which I have at RAID 5 on 3 scsi hd's.

Answer (score 0):

You burned it to a CD and not a DVD.  The current Ubuntu 13.10 .ISO release is 895MB, which will not fit on a standard CD.  Burn the image to a DVD, and reinstall.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think of this as being an issue because I did burn it to a DVD but I didn't check the format of the burn. I'll check and get back with you.

Comment: OK. I verified that the burn I created was a DVD (670meg of 4.38gig). The free space on the cd was 3.72 gig.

Comment: Burn it to DVD again using the slowest speed possible to ensure a good copy.  You shouldn't have any other problems with the disc if you do that.

Comment: OK. I downloaded a new ISO burner and used a new disc (I thought maybe the Microsoft burner wasn't using the proper format). The burn completed with 687241kb (1925 files and 926 folders). The format is DVD. I tried to use this new disc on the install and the same question is popping up. PS- I'll try the slowest burn this time.

Comment: No good. Burned the disc at 2x speed and verified the burn. I put the disc in and pressed enter but the same message is popping up. Just to clarify, I'm burning ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso to a dvd and I'm receiving a "media change" message asking me to insert the 13.10 saucy salamander (20131016).